# please help me to ask my question

Tags: support, asking-questions

I would very much like to be able to ask my question properly, but I do not know how to be "clearer" like @Hank Hoterman told me I should be.

Kindly, could you direct me to a place for beginner questions?

Thank you again and for your time. :)

Comment: By the way, I'm glad you're willing to learn, even though you don't know how to ask. Some other people, on the other hand, don't even **care**.

Comment: You have not offended us, don't worry.  We will have patience with you as long as you are patient with us as well.

Comment: @Justin 'jjngut' Nelson 4 secs ago many thanks

Comment: @PRASHANT, In a comment, the person's name is the part that is linked.  The part that looks like '4 minutes ago' is not part of a person's name.

Comment: @Justin 'jjnguy' Nelson i made pasting problem i will be more careful

Comment: Here's a link to the original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822307/how-do-i-pass-parameters-to-events ... or actually that's an edited version of the question: see that's question's edit history for the original version.

Comment: Definitely kudos for asking about how to ask and willingness to learn! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to ask a smart question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question)

Comment: @Justin 'jingut' Nelson 4 secs ago: OH HAI!

Comment: @PRASHANT, I gotta say, I don't buy it. If you look through my activity history -- admittedly, not an easy task -- you'll see that I'm often the first person to welcome new users to SO/MSO and offer to help them acclimate to our community. But in your case... if you merely had a "pasting problem," how did the 'y' in "jjnguy" become a 't'? And how did you _doubly_ misspell Henk Holterman's name? I do welcome you just as much as anyone else to our sites, but you have to put in _at least a little_ effort on your own.

Comment: Beg @George Stocker to keep making the awesome edits that he's been doing for you ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some tips:

Be very clear in your title.  Make sure your title describes your problem clearly.

In the body of your post, make sure that your question matches your title.  Make sure that you only ask one question at a time.  Include all of the relevant details, and leave out any details that are not needed.

That's a good place to get started.

You do not have to be perfect with your English.  People will help you fix that.  However, you do have to be close enough so that people can understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: The key part here is the relevant details. The words around can be fixed much more easily than the code sample can.

Comment: i am asking my question again with my friend to translate this time

Answer (score 9):

Here's a copy of your original question:

> ## c# how to delegate to events
>
> A problem I am having with the events
> of the c#
>
> some of my variables are not getting
>
> serialized per each entire method
> invocation.
>
> how do I know where arguments go???
>
> or am I in wrong locations about this!
>
> lately I have many compiler errors
>
> even reinstalling the .net provides no
> help.....

```
public static int button21_Click(object me, EventArgs MyArgs)
{
   button17(me, MyArts);
}
```

> Thank you,
>
> PRASHANT

---

Here are difficulties I have in trying to understand your question:

> some of my variables are not getting serialized per each entire method invocation.

What makes you think that a "variable" should be "serialized" at all, and why "per each entire method invocation"?

This is the first and only mention of "serialization" in the question, but it doesn't fit the title ("delegate to events") and doesn't fit the code sample.

> how do I know where arguments go???

I don't understand the question.

> lately I have many compiler errors

What compiler error[s], and what code generates those errors? Are you asking how to fix those compiler errors?

> even reinstalling the .net provides no help.....

Reinstalling the .net isn't the most likely way to fix compiler errors: a compiler error normally means a problem with your source code.

```
public static int button21_Click(object me, EventArgs MyArgs)
{
   button17(me, MyArts);
}
```

In what way does this code relate to the rest of the question?

Comment: Good breakdown.

Comment: i have some understanding,, i will increase

Answer (score 5):

Jon Skeet has a good post up on his blog on ["How to write the perfect question":](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Comment: i am not in complete understand of this but see some point

Answer (score 1):

Quoting your original question:

> lately I have many compiler errors 
>   even reinstalling the .net provides no help.....

If the compiler shows errors, that means your code is wrong. It doesn't mean the compiler has a problem and you do not need to re-install .NET.