# How can I know which question should be asked on which Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, scope

I have asked some questions on stackoverflow.com and programmers.stackexchange.com and they closed and down-voted due to off topic.

Now how can I consider that which is the best network site to ask my question?

Comment: This will be a long process. But you can decide by visiting site and checking its FAQ to know which kind of questions you should ask on that site.

Comment: 2/3 questions you've had closed on Stack Overflow were closed as duplicates. That doesn't mean you asked the question in the wrong place, it just means someone else asked it before you did. The last one was closed as "not a real question", which just meant that people didn't understand what you were trying to ask. Editing the question to clarify what you were actually asking would have been the right move there. So unless you've talking about questions you've now *deleted*, I don't think I understand the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each site has a FAQ link(example: [Stack Overflow FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)) - click on the FAQ link & review the FAQ page which will have what the on & off topic questions.

[image: faq link]

In general, most Stack Exchange sites will have these questions closed almost immediately as offtopic:

- Shopping/Buying Recommendations
- Polls
- Opinions ( I think x sucks, what about you?)

[image: not allowed topics]

Additionally, you might want to review per-site Meta to get a feel of what's allowed or not.

Finally, visit the [Stack Exchange directory](https://stackexchange.com/sites) to view a list of all available sites so you can judge for yourself the best Stack site for your question.

[image: Stack Exchange directory]

Comment: How about that – we both answered within the same second. Nice timing. :)

Comment: @KevinY Indeed :) a rare thing, this!

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow is for questions that have to do with the coding part of programming. Taken from [its FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), Stack Overflow covers questions about:

> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - matters that are unique to the programming profession

Programmers, on the other hand, is for "conceptual questions on software development". Again, taken from [its FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq), it covers:

> - Software engineering
> - Developer testing
> - Algorithm and data structure concepts
> - Design patterns
> - Architecture
> - Development methodologies
> - Quality assurance
> - Software law
> - Freelancing and business concerns

---

**Edit:** I initially misunderstood your question, so hopefully this edit helps.

Some questions are considered off-topic or not constructive, and will be closed because the question type doesn't work well with the Stack Exchange engine. This includes subjective questions, and questions that ask for list responses. Taken from the FAQ:

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
> - we are being asked an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”
> - it is a rant disguised as a question: “______ sucks, am I right?”

Comment: Subjective questions are not closed as off-topic, but as "non constructive."

Comment: Ahh yes, you're right. I'll edit that.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your questions, I don't think that they fit well on any stack exchange site.  If you want to know what is wrong with them, check out the close reasons, for instance:

> closed as not a real question
>   It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

and

> closed as not constructive
>   This question does not meet enough of our six guidelines for constructive subjective questions. All questions should be practical, answerable, and of some educational value to the greater community. Chatty, open-ended discussion questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

These aren't being closed for being off-topic, they are being closed because they simply don't fit the Stack Exchange question format.

In other words, it's not an issue of finding the right site to ask them, it's an issue of re-writing them so they are good questions that can be answered.

Consider spending some time reviewing [How to ask a smart question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question)