# How can I figure out which Stack Exchange site is the best one to ask a question on?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I know which question should be asked on which Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100714/how-can-i-know-which-question-should-be-asked-on-which-stack-exchange-site)

How can I figure out which Stack Exchange site is the best one to ask a question on?

For example, if I'm a programmer, and I want to ask a question about Eclipse, how do I know which site is the best to ask my question on?

- stackoverflow.com
- programmer.stackexchange.com
- or something else?

Is there a way to search the "about" pages for all Stack Exchange sites and see if I can find one that's a good match?

Comment: Every site has a FAQ linked at the top. Read those. And if in doubt, ask on the site-specific Meta.

Comment: P.s. if you really intend this to be a feature request (as originally tagged), make it a clear feature request. What you have now is more of a support question.

Answer (score 1):

Visiting https://stackexchange.com/sites gives you an overview of the stack exchange community of sites, and a brief overview of each. You can use this to help select which one might be best for your question, and click through to get more information.

A lot of this is going to depend on the *content* of your question:

- If you are writing a macro or extension for Eclipse, that belongs on Stack Overflow.
- If you are looking for suggestions about how to use Eclipse most efficiently in your workflow, that belongs on Programmers.

Questions about the use of a specific feature or problem specific to your install don't belong the SE network. They should be asked on some type of Eclipse-specific forum.