# How can I determine if a question is valid and good?

Tags: discussion, questions

How can I determine if the question I'm about to ask is a good and valid one? Are there guidelines I need to follow or a checklist I can go through?

Also what's the best way to make sure that I'm not accidentally asking a duplicate question?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [How to ask a smart question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question) Related: [How do I write a good title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can i know that question asked by me is a good question or not ?

- Does it follow the guidelines in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)?
- Does it follow the ones from [this blog post](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) by Jon Skeet?
- Does it follow the guidelines in [this blog series](http://odedcoster.com/blog/2010/07/28/getting-good-answers-on-stackoverflow-part-1-of-n/)? (full disclosure - this is my blog)

If the answer is yes to most or all of the above, the question is good.

> how can i find that it is not duplicate ?

Search. Look at the questions that come up after you finish typing up the title of your question.

When searching, use the relevant tags in `[]`.

Comment: where can i find guidelines of FAQ and blog post

Comment: @GauravVashishtha - I have posted them as links.

Comment: @Oded: Your site won't load for me: `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in {different file every time} on line n` Just a heads up in case something's wrong.

Comment: @Oded Yeap, max exec time for me too.

Comment: Teach me to use godaddy :(

Answer (score 2):

You can search for the key terms, and when you start asking, it will show you possible duplicates - check them to make sure your question has not been asked.

And if it is a duplicate, then someone will pick it up, and point you to the duplicate version. As long as you have taken care, this should not be considered a criticism.