# What is the frequency of the "Quality Filter" for re-evaluation the account which has "Ask Question" Ban?

Tags: support

What is the frequency of the "Quality Filter" for re-evaluation of the account which has "Ask Question" Ban?

Comment: You mean, when you have theoretically done everything needed to be unbanned, how long does it take the system to notice that and unban you? If you don't mean that, the quote is: *"Automatic bans never expire or "time out." This means that you cannot simply wait for a certain amount of time: if you do not take action, you will never be allowed to post again."*

Comment: Do you want question ban by asking unconstructive questions?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk Is that comment really necessary? If he is asking "how often/frequent does the system evaluate the eligibility to be banned/unbanned?", that seems to be a fair enough question. (Perhaps there is a dupe, I don't know. But I don't know the answer.)

Comment: @Bart Sir, I am genuinely interested in remaining on stackoverflow. And started improvising. Have undeleted my answer and working on improvising the sentences (Please not that English is my third language and not able to convincingly deliver technical things.)

Comment: Then stay. Improve what you have done. Contribute in whichever way you're still allowed. And if you improve enough, you'll be allowed to fully participate again at some point. What quantifies "enough" and when that exactly will be I can't tell you. But since you seem to take our comments constructively, rather than complain about them, I'm sure you'll be just fine. Good luck.

Comment: @Optimight: I had question ban for 3 times. I tried to understand is their any quality filter for asking question. But on MSO or anywhere you need to [ask smart question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question). Then check how people answers question and how ask question. This is the only way to understand quality filter by reading quality questions and answers.

Comment: @ Somnath Muluk Sir, please can you visit my questions and answers and pinpoint errors ( through comment or any other way). It will help me correcting my mistakes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can I do when getting "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?  (the answer is here, in this post)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

Comment: @Optimight - a lot of your questions have very long titles. You should make the titles shorter and less detailed, put the important content from the titles into the body of the questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I've heard from the SE team, there is no "Quality *ban*" that actually exists on your profile, only a check that is run on your account at time of posting that returns the "Sorry, we are no longer taking questions from this account" message. At any given time you will either be able to post or get the failure message; that's about as substantial as the "ban" really is.

So the "check" is really when you try to post. If you have actually improved your posts enough to no longer be banned you should theoretically be able to immediately post questions again (barring caching).

Comment: Sir, that means I have to go through all my posts and improvise the language, formatting or maybe make it comprehensive. As soon as I achieve this, I will be able to post again, right?

Comment: @Optimight I have no idea what was wrong with your posts, but per the [documentation on this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers/86998#86998) it's based on downvotes, improving your questions so that they are upvoted/have downvotes removed would help

Comment: Sir, Out of total 10, I had only one question with -3 votes, no other question had down vote. On the contrary, remaining question earned me 8 up vote. There was one question which brought "Tumbleweed" badge, which was actually fully technical question but maybe from very unpopular area.

Comment: @Optimight I note that now your Stack Overflow profile shows only eight questions. If you have deleted downvoted questions, that is the wrong approach. Deleted posts still count for the ban, and once deleted, you can't improve them anymore. You should maybe request an un-deletion of those questions from the moderators in order to improve them. If you seem earnestly interested in improving the questions, it's likely that a moderator would assist by undeleting.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Sir, I will definitely would like to recover those two question. One (got me tumbleweed) was genuinely technical question (maybe from a very unpopular area) so remained unanswered,no comments, no Up-down voting and very low views. I still need solution for that answer. Second was too theoretical or vague and vast, not suitable to SO QA format. Please guide, where to put request to Moderators for un-deleting the questions?

Comment: @Optimight Just flag one of your posts, explain the situation (link to this question), ask for help [undeleting the inadvertently deleted questions], and hope for the best.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Sir, is it not advisable to remove tumbleweed questions? I think badge name itself suggests that it should be removed. (Weeds are supposed to be removed)

Comment: @Optimight If it's not downvoted and you don't have many deleted posts, it shouldn't make a difference. The point is that if you have a question ban, it's bad to have deleted downvoted posts, because they still count for the ban, and when they are deleted, you can't improve them to get a better score for them. Anyway, another thing to improve your chances to get the ban lifted is to provide more answers (good enough to earn you upvotes). If you only have that one deleted question with a negative score, answers alone should be sufficient if you can't improve the score of the downvoted question.