# What should I do for my questions to be answered by other users rapidly

Tags: discussion, support, questions

I am working as Android programmer. I am working on some Android projects, where I need assistance from the Android experts here in Stack Overflow.

I posted my queries to Stack Exchange accounts, but the number of users that participate in answering the question quite few and also the response time is quite slow.

I found only 20 or 30 views on my post, although I have seen some posts with 200+ views.

What should I do to improve user participation and response time on my posts?

Comment: See For ans of question.http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question and https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: Make your question easy to answer quickly and clear. That usually means the smallest complete code to illustrate it and a "here's what I thought it should do". Make sure the title is good too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can offer a bounty on your questions. It attracts the attention of other users to a better extent.

For bounty related queries, refer to  ["How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7054/195231)

However wrapping question with suitable set of words can also do the task. For guidelines about how to phrase questions, read the [guidelines and FAQs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq)