# Got a reputation mark as user removed and unable to understand it properly

Tags: support, reputation

I am sorry to ask this question to moderators but I am unable to find any help for my query, I need to know why I have been given by -5 points which shows that user has been removed. What that exactly means? Does that mean I am no more part of the Stack Overflow community?
Also I am not getting any replies for my question, is it because I am not part of this community according to user removed remark as per my understanding?

Comment: Don't worry,  this is nothing against you. Its more loosing +5 that you got previously than getting -5

Answer (score 3):

> why I have been given by -5 points

A Stack Overflow user upvoted one of your question, so you received 5 reputation points. Sometime later that user was removed/deleted from Stack Overflow, so those 5 reputation points were removed from your profile.

> is it mean by I am no more part of stackoverflow community?

No, you are still a part of the Stack Overflow community

> I am not getting any replies for my question

Although not every question gets answered, however to improve the chances of getting answers [click here to read some tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Also read more suggestions here:

- [How to ask a smart question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question)
- [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)